# GWTP: Direct navigation to "place" doesn't work

Tags: java, url, url-routing, gwtp

I'm not sure why GWTP by default doesn't allow me to navigate directly to a place in my application by typing in the URL. What I mean by that is I can reveal a place by using `PlaceRequest`with the `NameToken`, but I can't go to the specified place by directly typing the path into the browser.

For example, I have a place `savestatistik`and I can load it by

```
PlaceRequest request = new PlaceRequest.Builder().nameToken(NameTokens.savestatistik).build();
```

and I can navigate there by clicking a link in the applcation and the URL changes from `http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApp.html` to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/savestatistik` and the contents of the place is displayed as required.

But, if I type in `http://127.0.0.1:8888/savestatistik` in my browser I get a 404 error.

Do I need to do some kind of GWTP specific URL mapping in addition to this? I haven't seen anything like this in any tutorials on the internet that deals with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing `<inherits name="com.wallissoftware.pushstate.PushState" />` from my `*.gwt.xml` file. Don't know what PushState even is but it seems to have fixed it.